# How to determine the number of stereoisomers of a di-substituted allene, exhibiting both axial and central chirality?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

What are the diastereomers and enantiomeric pairs of the compound below where A are chiral groups (central chirality)? There should be [3 diastereomers and 3 enantiomeric pairs](http://www.perekalin.narod.ru/Answers1.pdf) (last page).

[image]

[I previously asked a question about tetra-substituted allenes.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/36914/)

Comment: Have you tried to apply the Newman projection method I described in your previous question? If so, what problem do you run into?  Can you draw the the diastereomers you came up with?  Which ones are chiral?

Comment: Can't find three of them. I got the R,R (S,S), R,S (S,R), those are just two.

Comment: There are 2 R,R diastereomers, both chiral and 1 chiral R,S diastereomer - does that help?

Comment: Are the two R,R isomers are connected through axial chirality?

Comment: yes, sighting down the allene (Newman) one R,R diastereomer has front R at 0° and back R at 270°; other R,R diastereomer has front R at 0° and back R at 90°

Comment: Okay, I've got it, but that returns me to my previous question. Could you check my comment there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the three diastereomers with their enantiomers on the right side. The top and middle diastereomers are connected via axial chirality (R and S are used to mark the configuration of A groups).

[image]

Comment: Nice work, but all 3 are axially chiral.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good at this but here is something to work on. Each row is a pair of mirror images. Grey structures in 3rd row are identical to the respective 2nd row ones. 
[image]