# What symmetry elements mustn't a molecule possess to be considered achiral?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

Undergraduate textbooks say that a molecule mustn't posses a reflection plane and an inversion center to be considered achiral. As mentioned by Ron in his answer to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/36914/how-to-find-the-number-of-stereoisomers-of-a-tetra-substituted-allenes-exhibiti), molecules that don't possess a plane nor center of symmetry, but do possess an $S_4$ improper axis are considered to be achiral. Are there any other symmetry elements that need to be taken into consideration when determining whether a molecule is chiral or not?

Comment: Short answer: Anything that can be expressed in terms of $\mathrm{S}_n$ axes makes a molecule achiral (Schoenflies definition). Or alternatively, anything that can be expressed as $\bar n$ makes a molecule achiral (Hermann-Mauguin definition).

Comment: Actually, any reflection in a plane is just an $S_1$ operation, and an inversion through a point is just an $S_2$ operation. *So*, @Jan's comment is indeed the most concise yet complete definition: any $S_n$ axis present will make the molecule achiral.

Comment: Okay. I would like to see some exotic example :).

Comment: @Marko that's hard to find. Your best bet is looking for a molecule in the $S_4$ point group, which has the operations $E$, $S_4$, $C_2$, and $S_4^3$ - i.e. no mirror plane and no centre of inversion, but is still achiral because of the improper rotation axis. You can find some examples and pictures here http://csi.chemie.tu-darmstadt.de/ak/immel/tutorials/symmetry/index7.html

Comment: Nice examples, especially the coronane.

Comment: Someone may post an answer (with the examples).